Use generic type as type index
I'm trying to create a type structure which defines a set of projects (e.g. software projects), each with one or more apps (e.g. API and UI), each of which can have some strongly-typed configuration properties (secrets, env vars).
When I try what I have below, I get the errors:

Type 'TProjectKey' cannot be used to index type 'AllProjects'.
Type '"apps"' cannot be used to index type 'AllProjects[TProjectKey]'.
Type 'TAppType' cannot be used to index type
'AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"]'.
Type '"secrets"' cannot be used to index type
'AllProjects[TProjectKey]["apps"][TAppType]'.

My attempt is below -- see incline comments.
enum ProjectKey {
    Project1 = "projectOne",
    Project2 = "projectTwo",
}

enum AppType {
  API = "api",
  UI = "ui",
}

type Project<TProjectKey extends ProjectKey> = {
    key: TProjectKey;
    name: string;
    apps: Partial<{ [ TAppType in AppType ]: App<TAppType> }>;
}

type App<TAppKey extends AppType = AppType, TSecretKeys extends string = never> = {
    type: TAppKey;
    name: string;
    secrets: Secrets<TSecretKeys>;
}

type OptionalSecret = {
  defaultValue?: string;
};

type RequiredSecret = {
  required: true;
};

type Secret = OptionalSecret | RequiredSecret;

type Secrets<TSecretKeys extends string> = { [ K in TSecretKeys ]: Secret };

// Define a project.

const Project1: Project<ProjectKey.Project1> = {
    key: ProjectKey.Project1,
    name: "Project One",
    apps: {
        api: {
            type: AppType.API,
            name: "Project One API",
            secrets: {
                "SECRET_1": { required: true },
                "SECRET_2": { defaultValue: "abc" },
            },
        },
    },
};


// Roll up all projects into a mapped type.

type AllProjects = {
    [ ProjectKey.Project1 ]: typeof Project1;
};

// Define a configuration which describes all of the projects.

type Config = {
    [ TProjectKey in ProjectKey ]?: ProjectConfigProps<TProjectKey>;
};

type ProjectConfigProps<TProjectKey extends ProjectKey> = {
  apps: { [ TAppType in AppType ]: AppConfigProps<TProjectKey, TAppType> };
};

// Error occurs below.
type AppConfigProps<TProjectKey extends ProjectKey, TAppType extends AppType> = {
  secrets?: {
    [ TSecretKey in keyof AllProjects[ TProjectKey ][ "apps" ][ TAppType ][ "secrets" ] ]:
        AllProjects[ TProjectKey ][ "apps" ][ TAppType ][ "secrets" ][ TSecretKey ] typeof RequiredSecret
        ? { value: string }
        : { value?: string }
    };
};


// Usage -- the goal is to strongly type the configuration object so that each required secret must be provided, and each optional one may or may not.

const config: Config = {
    "projectOne": {
        apps: {
            api: {
                secrets: {
                    SECRET_1: { value: "some_required_value" },
                    SECRET_2: { value: "some_default_value" },
                    // Or SECRET_2 can just not be supplied.
                }
            },

            // How to make this not required if there are no required secrets?
            ui: {
                secrets: undefined, 
            },
        },
    },
};

Check it out in the playground.

Your playground has at least one syntax error, with a typeof RequiredSecret sort of hanging out there, and I don't even understand what typeof could possibly mean there. Since you're not mentioning the syntax errors, maybe it's a typo in your code?  Could you please [edit] so we're not distracted by weird syntax issues and we can focus on the underlying issue (not that I quite understand what it is yet)?

The more I look at this, the messier it is. Type 'TProjectKey' cannot be used to index type 'AllProjects'. is a valid error because AllProjects has no ProjectKey.Project2 key. Is that just a lapse in the example and not fundamental to the problem you're trying to ask about?  The goal of a [mre] is to really give a self-contained and focused demonstration of a single issue. If you're getting a bunch of errors in your example, it's a sign that you might be accidentally asking about multiple things, some of which you don't really have as a problem. Could you please [edit] to tidy it up?

I've unmuddled this as far as I can without knowing more about what you're trying to do. This playground link is as close as I can get to making sense. If I see an [edit] here to make the example more of a [mre] and explain more clearly what the goal is, I'll re-engage. Otherwise, good luck!

@jcalz thanks for your help. Sorry, I know it's a confusing thing. It's very close based on what you have given in your playground link. I updated the post with my example, with your changes. See the comment at the bottom, if you have time, that's what I'm stuck on now.

Shouldn't the code be a [mre] of your original problem (presumably having to do with the errors in your question text, which are, as far as I can tell, completely gone now) and not what you're stuck on now? It's a little unpleasant to see what looks like my fixes to your actual problem rolled into the question.

I commented on that above. This  was/is the smallest repro I could give. The real code has far more. Your changes helped me get to the core issue which is now reflected above.

If your real code had the errors you were originally asking about, and my playground link fixed those, then I would really appreciate it if you would revert to a version where those errors are present and then we can answer that question with my fixes. And if you have a problem after that, you could open a new question for it.  If you couldn't express the core issue of the question without my fixes, I'm not sure how to proceed. It's not that I don't want to help, far from it. But from my end this looks like scope creep and I'd worry about it happening again, when you find a deeper issue.

Sure, reverted.

So, backing up, the typeof thing is a typo, right? It's not where you get those errors in your question. So could you fix it so that the code is a [mre] that actually demonstrates what you're saying here? I assume typeof should be... extends... I think. The goal here I'd think, would be to get to a point where the question actually has a single issue (and it should be one of the ones you're asking about).  Maybe like this?

The typeof there was not a typo, it was just incorrect. The question, as it is, is the minimum, until i saw your solution. So you can either have it as it is (IMO the minimum even with the incorrect syntax) or I can update it w/your suggestions but I got in trouble for that earlier, so ... :-D

But... your question doesn't mention the scads of syntax errors that occur in your example. Things like "declaration or statement expected". Either explicitly ask about that (although then you've just got multiple issues related only because they're in your code) or fix it so that it's not present. And I'm still not sure how you wrote X typeof Y ? T : U instead of X extends Y ? T : U and maintain that it's not a typo.  Maybe you should break that into its own question: "I'm trying to write X typeof Y ? T : U but it doesn't work and gives me all kinds of errors, what am I doing wrong?"

X typeof Y ? T : U was not a typo because I intended to type it, even though it was wrong.

Right, but since you didn't even mention that problem in your question, it's out of scope here. If you want to fix that so you can still ask about the problems that you did ask about, and then open a new question about X typeof Y ? T : U, that would be more well-scoped for Stack Overflow, to my understanding. But it seems we're at an impasse and it might be better for me to just disengage so as reduce noise (and maybe I'll delete my comments so that anyone else isn't unduly deterred by this conversation, as it was ultimately fruitless). Good luck!

@jcalz -- thank you, by the way, I was able to push forward with my crazy config typing with your help. I'd be happy to accept an answer if you want to provide one.
